# GraphDB load triples from URI

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb

I'm trying to use the following SPARQL syntax with GraphDB.  I've never used it anywhere else before, so I don't have a good sense of whether it's official.

See also [Using the 'GRAPH' keyword in SPARQL to fetch remote graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969377/using-the-graph-keyword-in-sparql-to-fetch-remote-graphs)

```
LOAD <http://raw.githubusercontent.com/evidenceontology/evidenceontology/master/eco.owl> INTO GRAPH <http://example.com/loaded>
```

When I try to load an `RDF/XML` file with an `.owl` extension, I generally get an error message like

> Internal Server Error (#500)
>
> White spaces are required between publicId and systemId. [line 1,
>   column 63]

When I try to load a turtle file with a `.ttl` extension, I generally get something more like

> Internal Server Error (#500)
>
> IRI included an unencoded space: '32' [line 1]

***What am I doing wrong?***

Comment: This does work for me, when replacing your ontology URI  with `https://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl`, and doesn't work when replacing your ontology URI with `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owlcs/pizza-ontology/master/pizza.owl`.

Comment: Indeed it's [official](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/#load)

Comment: Something is weird with the file encoding that Github returns. I downloaded the raw file to disk and then loaded it successfully via `LOAD <file:///tmp/eco.owl> INTO GRAPH <http://example.com/loaded>`

Comment: On the other hand, when I tried your query with the Github URL, I got `There was a fatal failure during preparation of 8f341e54-9584-4d2d-a201-aa44bcede427 org.openrdf.rio.RDFParseException: IRI included an unencoded space:   [line 1]` (I used Stardog)

Comment: Solution: Use RawGit which "serves raw files directly from GitHub with proper Content-Type headers": https://cdn.rawgit.com/evidenceontology/evidenceontology/master/eco.owl You can find the service [here](https://rawgit.com/)

Comment: @AKSW thanks for the RawGit suggestion.  I do have the ontology that I'd like to `LOAD` on github, but it's currently a password protected repository.  I also have it in the web root directory of an AWS server and I can view it in a web browser, but trying to load that results in the same error messages I quoted in my question.  **TL;DR:**  Since this clearly works under some circumstances, I guess I need to investigate what's happening to my encoding.

Comment: Right, something is strange. One difference is the content type in the response header: `curl -I -L http://raw.githubusercontent.com/evidenceontology/evidenceontology/master/eco.owl` leads to `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` On the other hand, `https://cdn.rawgit.com/evidenceontology/evidenceontology/master/eco.owl ` returns `Content-Type: application/rdf+xml;charset=utf-8
`